# Customize mapping request parameters and fields inside the DTO ?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-binding, spring-mvc-initbinders

I have the following class:

```
public class MyDTO { 

       private String kiosk;
       ...
}
```

and following url:

```
http://localhost:1234/mvc/controllerUrl?kiosk=false
```

and following controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = APPLICATION_JSON)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<List<?>> getRequestSupportKludge(final MyDTO myDTO, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ...
}
```

Now it is working nice and boolean field resolves properly.

Now url parameter has changed like this:

```
http://localhost:1234/mvc/controllerUrl?new_kiosk=false
```

I don't want to change parameter name inside the DTO. Is there way to say spring to understand  that `new_kiosk` request parameter value should be put into `kiosk` field ?

Comment: What is the data type(JSON/XML etc) that you are accepting from front end?

Comment: @RE350 It is just get parameters. url like this **controllerUrl?new_kiosk=false**

Comment: I strongly suggest a read of the java bean specification. A property is just the name of the getter/setter how the field is named internally doesn't matter. If your field is named `foo` and you have a `setBar` method that sets the value of `foo` you have a `bar` property. Property != field.

Comment: @M. Deinum it is surprise for me. I always use IDE set get generator. By default it generates set and get methids accordin field names.

Comment: @M. Deinum Do you suggest to create methods with names **setNew_kiosk** and **getNew_kiosk**  ?

Comment: Ofcourse it does as that is in 99% of the cases correct. However as mentioned the property name doesn't have to match the field name (I strongly suggest a read of the java beans spec. which explains all of that).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apart from setting an additional setter you can hande the case by making a custom argument resolver. There's a few ways you can go about it, but there's already a well discussed [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986593/how-to-customize-parameter-names-when-binding-spring-mvc-command-objects). If I were you I would focus on the jkee's answer. Follow it step by step, and than all you should do is annotate your DTO with something like,

```
public class MyDTO { 

       @ParamName("new_kiosk")
       private String kiosk;
       ...
}
```

Note that even if you can't change `MyDTO` class, you can still follow a custom resolver route. In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469887/spring-mvc-default-values-for-fields-of-method-parameter/29471278#29471278) I've answered how you can write a parameter type annotation. Combining the two post you can easily come up with an annotation e.g. `@ParamMapper` that would define the mapping from request to properties. Think of something like

```
 getRequestSupportKludge(@ParamMapper("new_kiosk;kiosk") MyDTO myDTO, BindingResult bindingResult)
```

Answer (score 4):

There different ways to do that.

If you can change `MyDTO` class the simplest way is to add a setter as suggested by M.Deinum :

```
public class MyDTO { 

       private String kiosk;
       ...
       public void setNew_kiosk(String kiosk) {
           this.kiosk = kiosk;
       }
}
```

That way, you can process `http://localhost:1234/mvc/controllerUrl?kiosk=false` as well as `http://localhost:1234/mvc/controllerUrl?new_kiosk=false`

If you are not allowed to do that (because the DTO is part of a library you are not allowed to change or ...), you can use a filter mapped to `/mvc/controllerUrl`, that would wrap the request with a custom `HttpServlerRequestWrapper` that will override following methods :

```
String  getParameter(String name)
Map<String,String[]>    getParameterMap()
Enumeration<String>     getParameterNames()
String[]    getParameterValues(String name)
```

calling the underlying request methods and processing the special parameter name. Example :

```
String[]    getParameterValues(String name) {
    String[] values = req.getParameterValues(name); // req is the wrapped request
    if ("kiosk".equals(name) && (values == null) {  // will accept both names
        values = req.getParameterValues("new_kiosk"); // try alternate name
    }
    return values;
}
```

This will be much harder to write and test, so only go that way if you cannot modify `MyDTO` class.

You could also try to use a custom implementation of `WebBindingInitializer`. From [Spring Framework Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-webdatabinder) :

*To externalize data binding initialization, you can provide a custom implementation of the `WebBindingInitializer` interface, which you then enable by supplying a custom bean configuration for an `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`, thus overriding the default configuration.*

Beware : the recommended usage of that is to register custom editors for a whole application - not your use case. And Spring Framework is oftern described as *easy to extend but not to override*. Caveat emptor ...

Summary : try to use method 1, if you cannot, then use method2, and only try method3 if you have other reasons to use a custom `WebBindingInitializer`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `@JsonProperty` on the field of the DTO for mapping it with the request JSON, if the field name in the request is different from the field defined in the DTO.